# create offline SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to create and save the offline SQLite database for send job profile given below .But the the database is not created. Please tell me how to create SQLIite database and represent that in the file explorer.

Fragment.java

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.*;

public class FragmentSendJob extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    // this Fragment will be called from MainActivity

    private Button submit,cancel;
    private EditText ename,mobno,picktime,unit,street,suburb,destination,fare,city;
    private Spinner state,group;
    private ViewGroup vgroup ;
    private String sename,smobno,spicktime,sunit,sstreet,ssuburb,sstate, ssendjob,scity,sdestination,sfare,sgroup,login_token;
    private static FragmentDialog dialog;
    private  SendJobDataBase db; 
    static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private Typeface ftype;
     private SharedPreferences pref1;
    String latitude,longitude;
    public FragmentSendJob(){}

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sendjob_fragment, container, false);
        pref1=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LocDetails", getActivity().MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        latitude = pref1.getString("latitude","latitude"); 
        longitude = pref1.getString("longitude","longitude"); 

        ename = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ename);
        mobno  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobno);
        picktime  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.picktime);
        unit  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
        street  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.street);
        suburb  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.suburb);
        destination  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.destination);
        state = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.state);
        fare=(EditText)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.fare);
        group = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.group);
        city  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.city);
        vgroup = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rel); 
        submit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    new SendJob().execute();
                Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),GetCurrentLocation.class);
                startActivity(intent); 

                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+latitude+"***********");
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+longitude+"***********");


                }

            });

        cancel = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0, count = vgroup.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
                    View view = vgroup.getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof EditText) {
                        ((EditText)view).setText("");
                    }
                }

                }       
        });

        String[] mystate= new String[]{"Select state","New South Wales","Victoria","Queensland","Northern Territory","Western Australia","South Australia"};        
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.listrow, mystate);

        state.setAdapter(adapter);  

                state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                scity =  state.getSelectedItem().toString();

                   String s1=arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                        if(s1.equals("New South Wales"))
                            city.setText("Sydney");
                        else if(s1.equals("Victoria"))
                            city.setText("Melbourne");
                        else if(s1.equals("Queensland"))
                            city.setText("Brisbane");
                        else if(s1.equals("Northern Territory"))
                            city.setText("Darwin");
                        else if(s1.equals("Western Australia"))
                            city.setText("Perth");
                        else if(s1.equals("South Australia"))
                            city.setText("Adelaide");

                             }
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });


                String[] mygroups= new String[]{"Select Groups","My Group","My Secondary group","Everyone"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                        R.layout.listrow, mygroups);
                group.setAdapter(adapters);

                group.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int pos, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                ssendjob = group.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                                //gender.setText(setgender);
                            }

                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
        return rootView;
       }




       private class SendJob extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
        {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                try 
                {
                JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                sename = ename.getText().toString();
                smobno = mobno.getText().toString();
                spicktime = picktime.getText().toString();
                sunit = unit.getText().toString();
                sstreet = street.getText().toString();
                ssuburb = suburb.getText().toString();
                sstate = state.getSelectedItem().toString();
                scity = city.getText().toString();
                sdestination = destination.getText().toString();
                sgroup = group.getSelectedItem().toString();
                sfare = fare.getText().toString();

                sename.replace("" ,"%20");
                smobno.replace("" ,"%20");
                spicktime.replace("" ,"%20");
                sunit.replace("" ,"%20");
                sstreet.replace("" ,"%20");
                sstate.replace("" ,"%20"); 
                ssuburb.replace("" ,"%20");
                scity.replace("" ,"%20");
                sdestination.replace("" ,"%20");
                sgroup.replace("" ,"%20");
                sfare.replace("" ,"%20");

                     job.put("name",sename);
                     job.put("mobile_no",smobno);
                     job.put("pickup_time",spicktime);
                     job.put("unit_no",sunit);
                     job.put("street_name",sstreet);
                     job.put("state",sstate);
                     job.put("suburb",ssuburb);
                     job.put("city",scity);
                     job.put("destination",sdestination);
                     job.put("group",sgroup);
                     job.put("fare",sfare);
                     job.put("latitude",latitude);
                     job.put("longitude",longitude);

                     job.put("status_key","2");
                     job.put("method","send_job");
                     job.put("login_token",login_token);

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(se);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    Log.i("response", data);

                    System.out.println("response "+data);
                    String call;
                    call = data;

                                System.out.println("print me............."+call);


                                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                                Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));




                                db = new SendJobDataBase(getApplicationContext());  

                                db.insert(sename,smobno, spicktime, sunit, sstreet,sstate, ssuburb,scity, sdestination, sgroup, sfare);
                                  db.open();    


                                if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                                {
                                    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    alert.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                                    alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) 
                                        {
                                            pDialog.dismiss();


                                dialog.dismiss();



                                         }
                                    });
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            alert.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                                    alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();


                                        }
                                    });
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                                    {
                                        public void run() 
                                        {
                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                            alert.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                            }
                            catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }



                        }
                        return params;
                    }
                    private Context getApplicationContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
                    {

                        super.onPostExecute(result);

                    }       
       }




    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: check this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Android has a built-in SQLite DB that you can use.

**Creating a DB table**

```
public abstract class DBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public DBManager(Context context,String tableName, String [] columns) {

super(context, “test.db”, null, 1);
}
```

**Executing SQL code**

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.CALL_PHONE”></uses-permission>
db.execSQL( “create table ...” );
```

**Inserting Data:**

```
getWritableDatabase().insert(tableName, null, values);
```

**Getting Data:**

```
getReadableDatabase().query(...);
```

Hope this helps